# Is collection synchronizing (via Collections.synchronizedX) necessary when access methods are synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

There is a lot of topics when synchronization in Java appears. In many of them is recommended to using invokation of Collections.synchronized{Collecation, List, Map, Set, SortedMap, SortedSet} instead of Collection, List, etc. in case of multithreading work to thread-safe access.

Lets imagine situation when some threads exist and all of them need to access collection via methods that have synchronized block in their bodies.

So then, is it necessary to use:

```
    Collection collection = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<T>());
```

or only

```
    Collection collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

need to?

Maybe you can show me an example when second attempt instead of first will cause evidently incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the contrary, `Collections.synchronizedCollection()` is generally not sufficient because many operations (like iterating, check then add, etc.) need additional, explicit synchronization.

If every access to the collection is already done through properly synchronized methods, then wrapping the collection again into a syncronized proxy is useless.

Comment: So when using of Collections.synchronizedCollection() is needed? I mean replacing it by ordinary collection constructor will cause bad behaviour/error.

Comment: It's never absolutely needed, since you can always synchronize the accesses to the collection by yourself. But it can be handy if the guarantees it provides are sufficient, or if you only have one or two among 25 cases where explicit additional synchronization is needed.

Comment: Could you please point out such case when explicit synchonization is needed? I have got some doubts because I read that appliance of only explicit synchonization is incorrect (not sufficient). Now you tell me that when methods are properly synchronized - collections wrapping is useless. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: `for (Object o : collection) {System.out.println(o);}`. Do that with a synchronized collection, while another thread modifies the collection, and you'll have an exception. Sure, the collection itself won't be corrupted, but you probably don't want an exception to be thrown while iterating over the collection. For this loop to be safe, you'll need `synchronized(collection) {for (Object o : collection) {System.out.println(o);}}`. Other example: `if (c.size() < 10) { c.add(o); }`.

Comment: I created two threads. One for printing and one for adding new element to collection (without synchronization block in their bodies). I checked this with Collections.synchronizedCollection() and with collection constructor. No exception was thrown.

Comment: Is it possible to have situation where replacing Collections.synchronizedCollection() by collection constructor cause some damage?

Comment: Of course it's possible. As soon as you access a non-thread-safe collection from multiple threads, where at least one modifies the collection, it's a problem waiting to appear. Whether you synchronize the access by yourself or you use the synchronizedCollection wrapper doesn't change anything.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/10005906 for an example of iteration failing on a synchronized list.

Comment: Thanks for your example. Maybe you've got something similar to show exception/error after replacing Collections.synchronizedCollection() by collection constructor?

Comment: Tkank you very much! Now I know what I was doing wrong. I did not remember about join method... That is why my examples made me more confused.

Answer (score 0):

No, if your access methods are synchronized there is no need to also use a synchronized collection.

```
Collection collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will do just fine in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already arranged for proper synchronization of your code, you definitely do not need another layer of synchronization on the lower level of granularity.

Just make sure when you say

> all of them need to access collection via methods that have synchronized block in their bodies.

that all these blocks use the same lock. It is not enough to just involve *some* synchronized block.